# When I use powershell perform decompression, how to list the files in the running

Tags: windows, powershell, unzip, compression

As title，
When I use PowerShell perform decompression, the command line window just show the command like

```
'powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command "& { Add-Type -A 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'; [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('X:\XXX\XXX.zip', '.'); }"'
```

But I want to know which file is in decompress.

I'm not sure is there any parameter that I can add in that command?
Or just I'm using incorrect parameter cause the log is not showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ExtractToDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485709(v=vs.110).aspx) method doesn't provide any outputs or logs. You may have to use a third party tool like [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or use the COM-Object [Shell.Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774063(v=vs.85).aspx) to open the Zip and copy each item by yourself where you can also add your desired outputs.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser.
But because I have to make an installation file, so I may not be directly install a third-party tool.
Or I can add some parameters to see the current progress of decompress?

Comment: Not with the ExtractToDirectory method.

Comment: OK, I see. Thank you very much.